# Why did Ethereum choose RANDAO rather than VRF for PoS?

Tags: randomness, vrf

I think RANDAO and VRF have different pros and cons for constructing a random number.

And I read that RANDAO is very useful when it comes with VDF.

But RANDAO is currently adapted without VDF (but with plans).

Then, what were the biggest reasons to choose RANDAO rather than VRF at that time for Ethereum?

Sorry if I didn't find a proper document related to this issue.